# How to generate a Javascript code that can be copied and pasted onto a website to render an RSS feed in HTML?

Tags: javascript, rss, embed

I would like to share my websites RSS feeds from a code snippet that users can cut and paste into their own websites. Any ideas?

Comment: you could have a `textarea` and place you javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can write server-side code that renders your RSS feed as formatted HTML, then put that URL in an `<iframe>`.